# Python- Tracking bytes parsed while parsing

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I wish to know if there is something that help me keep track of HTML bytes parsed vs string (i.e. between tags text) parsed while parsing.

How can I do so?

Comment: It depends on how you're parsing the HTML. Some libraries expose this as, e.g., an `offset` attribute of each `Element` object; others give you a way to hook reading/feeding into the parser so you can keep track of what you've fed in that way; etc. Without knowing what library you're using and seeing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates how you're using it, it's hard to give a specific answer.

Comment: I am keen on using BeautifulSoup for HTML parsing. My main objective is to track of HTML parsed vs Text Parsed. I found that there is no option of hook or offset in BeautifulSoup. Do you know other library that can be instrumental in doing so?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` actually sits on top of [`lxml`, `html5lib`, and `html.parser`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), all of which either expose positions or can be hooked. It's a bit clumsy to require one of the three, but a bit of work to  wrap all three of them, but either one works.

Comment: Do you know a tutorial on how to use the offset/ hook or how the parsers in python works?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. You might want to pick one (probably either `lxml` because it's fast and powerful and pretty clean, or `html.parser` because it's built into the stdlib) and ask a more specific question for that. But first read the docs and see how far you can get on your own.

Comment: Do you know where can I find htmllib.py. I am not able to find it in site-packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58244/discussion-between-mousecoder-and-abarnert).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't on when you wanted to chat. Anyway, `htmllib.py` is part of the stdlib in Python 2.x, which in most installations means it's under a `lib/pythonX.Y` directory rather than a `site-packages`, or you can find it online in the [Hg repo](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/htmllib.py). In 3.x, you can't find it because it doesn't exist. But why are you looking for that? It's been deprecated since 2.6 (in favor of `HTMLParser`/`html.parser`), and `BeautifulSoup` doesn't know how to work with it.